# Need 100% result in Test Class : In PageReference

Tags: class, testing, salesforce, apex

**Class**:

```
public with sharing class contactInsert {
    public contact myC{get;set;}
    public contactInsert(){
        myC = new Contact();
    }
    public PageReference iSave(){
        insert myC;
        return new pageReference('/'+myC.id);
    }
}
```

**Page**:

```
<apex:page controller="contactInsert"><br>
    <apex:form ><br>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!myC.firstname}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!myC.lastname}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!myC.email}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!myC.phone}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!iSave}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I created Test Class but it cant recover PageReference :

```
@isTest
public with sharing class TestcontactInsert {
    @isTest
    private static void myTest(){
        contact c = new contact(firstname='fnam',lastname='lnam',email='a@a.com',phone='89898989');
        insert c;

         PageReference pageRef = Page.InsertContact;
         Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

         ContactInsert ci = new ContactInsert();
         ci.iSave();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to the `myC` Contact property on `ci` to a Contact that hasn't been inserted yet. If you don't, you will get a Null reference exception from the `insert myC;` line.